# Change CSS of sibling image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, mousehover

I have a DIV with 9 images and I would like to change CSS property of 8 images unlike one that user is hovering.
Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="#" class="gallerie-image"><img src="http://i.utdstc.com/icons/256/google-chrome-mac.png" class="image-hover" onmouseover="return hoverPics()" onmouseout="return changeMeBack()" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="gallerie-image"><img src="http://i.utdstc.com/icons/256/google-chrome-mac.png" class="image-hover" onmouseover="return hoverPics()" onmouseout="return changeMeBack()" /></a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function hoverPics() {
        $(".image-hover").css("filter", "gray").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");

        $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
}
function changeMeBack() {
        $(".image-hover").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
}
```

[Actual page](http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1032/4df6f1451c32ee0eb6d297da283d96a7/lilianpix.ru/photos.html)


The best example of what I'm looking for is Gallery at the bottom of the page after age validation. [Here](http://www.rockstargames.com/V/)
Cheers

Comment: @devqon CSS siblings only work for downstream elements — the selector do not include previously occurring siblings.

Comment: You need to pass `this` in  hoverPics() and use that inside function. [See  this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4yh85h1p/)

Comment: @Terry you're right didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend against using inline JS. Since you're already using jQuery, you can simply listen to the [`.hover()` event](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) (which is basically a shorthand for `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`), and use DOM traversal methods:

```
$(function() {
    $('.image-hover').hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)'
        }).parent().siblings().find('.image-hover').css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(100%)'
        });
    }, function() {
        $('.image-hover').css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)'
        });
    });
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5kw2hs7f/

---

There is also a pure CSS method (slightly hackier), although it allows less granularity over control compared to the jQuery solution. The way is to set all `.image-hover` to grayscale, but only allow colour on the specific `.image-hover:hover`.

The only problem is that we are setting all images to greyscale as long as the parent container `.gallery` is hovered upon, and this might not be the desired behavior. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/88v8ga5z/

```
.gallery:hover .image-hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.gallery:hover .image-hover:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Looks fresh, I will change the code as you provided. By now I used advice from @anpsmn and now it works. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Pass this in function to access them

```
 onmouseover="return hoverPics(this)" onmouseout="return changeMeBack()"
```

in js

```
function hoverPics(obj) {
        $(".image-hover").css("filter", "gray").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");

        $(obj).css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
}
function changeMeBack() {
        $(".image-hover").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to verify if is hover, like this:

```
function hoverPics() {

    if( ! $('.image-hover').is(':hover') ) {
          $(".image-hover").css({ "filter": "gray", "-webkit-filter": "grayscale(100%)" });
    }
}
function changeMeBack() {
        $(".image-hover").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with jQuery however if attempting this I would pass through the id of the current element when the function is called, on hover. I would then use a loop to run through the images, within this loop I would check the id against the current image and if true would not change the grey scale.